# What's the recommended flag for suspicious posts?

Tags: support

I flagged a "question" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35855960/create-form-java-to-pdf) as spam as the post is IMO suspicious as it uses a shortened link to a `.exe` file, (obviously) to bypass the filter.

As the flag got disputed I'm curious about the recommended handling of "questions" like that, being aware that it actually might not be spam, but unwanted in either case - I therefore also voted to close it.

---

And is there any point in allowing shortened URLs at all?

Comment: That should have been deleted outright.  Links are bad enough, but an link to an executable?  NO!   Why would anyone dispute a flag on that?  Get rid of it!

Comment: Looks like a link to a zip to me. The zip *does contain* a .exe and .amo though. The .exe looks to be some packed Java .jar.

Comment: As to your question about allowing shortened URLs: they're normally not allowed, but this one was using a sufficiently obscure link-shortening service that it slipped through.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yeah, I deleted that. A shortened URL to an .exe that someone wants us to run? At the best, that's a question I can't see a way to salvage.

As for the flag, it was [disputed in review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11542482) when three people voted that the question needed to be edited. I'm pretty sure that's not what this post needed.

Even had it been reviewed by a moderator, there's a chance we would have disputed a spam flag, as it's not obviously promotional for a product or website. It's suspicious and weird, but maybe not true spam. Spam flags can carry heavy penalties, so we can be a little more cautious with them. Disputed flags don't count against you, it's like the flag never existed.

In this case, I'd use a custom flag and point out what you did here about the link. That would make it obvious to us what's going on, and we'd most likely mark anything like that as helpful.

Comment: But custom flags can take a long time before they get acted on, spam flags tend to get much quicker results.    If the exe contained a virus for example, then speed of removal would be important.

Comment: If I saw that post, I would have edited out the link as I have enough rep to do so AND flagged it with a custom message.

Comment: @IanRingrose That'd be the proper of way doing so IMHO, the problem is just that the privilege of editing without approval requires a certain amount of reputation, resulting in many users not being able to act properly.

Comment: @Seth True, but in my (few days :P) experience it doesn't tend to take too long to get edits approved/rejected, and I imagine an edit like that would take even less time, assuming the edit message pointed out the exe link removal.